# What does got mean in "they've got to leave"

Tags: verbs, past-tense, past-participles

> They've got to leave.

In the sentence above, what does "got"" mean? Is it the past participle of "get"? If not, what is it? Why bother add it? Why don't people just say

> They have to leave

Comment: It is an intensifier.

Comment: See also [#2](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/got)

Comment: See [this](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/have-got-to-and-have-to). It's impossible to say _why_ people use _have got_ in colloquial speech - we just do!

Comment: If they said "They have to leave", you could ask "Why didn't they say *they've got to leave*?"  Every language has more than one way to phrase things.